# Show the tax line when rate is 0% in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, checkout, tax

I’m updating to the latest version of WooCommerce from a very old version. I have noticed that when using the option “Display tax totals: Itemized”, the Tax name is not displayed anymore in the Sub Total line included in Cart page, Checkout page and in any customer e-mail, invoice, etc.

The reason appears to be that if the Tax rate is set to 0.0000%, the new version of WooCommerce automatically hides that line after the Sub Total, look below:

[image: No Tax Name]

If I set rates to 1.0000% or whatever, it appears. This exactly the way I want things to be displayed, look below:

[image: Tax Name displayed]

The problem is that I need that information to be displayed, the VAT rates in my store are always 0% due to a VAT extemption regime (*see screenshot*), but depending on the customer country I need to write what Tax extemption is being used, and I’m using the Tax name for that.

[image: My Tax rates right now]

Any ideas to force the displaying of the Tax name even if the rate is set at 0.0000%?

If that is not possible, how can I create a shortcode with the Tax name so I can use it at least in my order invoice, emails, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is very simple, just one line. It will display tax line, even if the tax rate is **`0%`**. Try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );
```

And optionally for orders:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec I have a similar issue with the extension Woocommerce Print Invoices & Packing lists, if you have the time I'd like you to chime in :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/50506596/3740119

Comment: @anotherbreed I will take a look :)