# Show Tax row in my invoice using Woocommerce Print Invoices & Packing lists

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, invoices

I opened a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231536/show-tax-line-when-the-rate-is-0-in-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout-pages) about forcing WooCommerce to show the Tax name in the checkout page of WooCommerce even if the rate is 0.000%, as I need that information to be displayed (VAT rates in my store are always 0% due to a VAT extemption regime, but it needs to be displayed). See the image below about how Taxes are currently managed:

[image: Tax rates]

I used this code in my function.php file to force WooCommerce to display the Tax name in Cart or during Checkout:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );
```

It works, and this is the result, the Tax name is displayed right before the Total row:

[image: Checkout template]

The problem comes when using the extension called Woocommerce Print Invoices & Packing lists, which is supposed to show the same stuff during the checkout, but the table row about Taxes is completely missing, check how the table appears in the Invoice:

[image: Invoice template]

Any ideas to force the displaying of the Tax name like the Checkout example above? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. This worked for me with 'WooCommerce PDF Invoices and Packing Slips'.

[WooCommerce PDF Invoice showing zero tax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6OcT.jpg)

Add this line to functions.php to display zero tax on the site:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );
```

Add this line to display zero tax on your invoices:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks man! That also worked in the e-mail template for the customer (email-order-details.php).