# Woocommerce Block Checkout Show Zero Rate Tax

Tags: woocommerce, block, checkout

In my Woocommerce Blocks checkout I would like to show the zero rate vat as "incl tax".

Here you see how it appears when I give a country (US in this case) a 1% VAT rate:
[vat rate US 1%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFo2R.png)

And here you see how it appears when I give it a 0% rate:
[vat rate US 0%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7qhz.png)
No VAT text appears, is it possible to make Woo say: Including taxes

Here's a link towards my shop:
https://bloomming.com/room-dividers/hanging-room-dividers

I found this thread: [Show the tax line when rate is 0% in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231536/show-the-tax-line-when-rate-is-0-in-woocommerce)
Solved by @LoicTheAztec

And tried these shortcodes:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );
```

But they didn't work, maybe because I'm using the Woocommerce Block checkout instead of the regular Woo checkout?

Hope you guys know a solution, thanks so much!